# Need to detect second extreme points of the image using Contour

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect the second extreme points of the image using Contour.

I am trying to do like below.

1. I am finding all the Contour of the image.
2. Sort the contour NumPy array
3. Delete the last element in the Numpy array to remove the external contour so as not to consider in extreme points detection.
4. Select the extreme points

below is the code:

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r"SimpleBoxTest.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

c=sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
c = np.delete(c, (-1), axis=0) 

extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/TestCode/DocumentLayoutDetection/extreamPoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Below image is just a reference image, I will be trying for other images also 
[image: Input image]

Image 2
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete the last element, you can get the second element from the end.

- Result of `c=sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)` is not a NumPy array it's a **list**.
  You can check the type using `type(c)`, and the result is `<class 'list'>`.
  You can delete the last element using `del`: `del c[-1]`, but you don't have to.
- Use: `c = c[-2]` for extracting the second last element for the list.
  Now `type(c)` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.
- Find the minimum and maximum using `extLeft = c[:, :, 0].min()` and `extRight = c[:, :, 0].max()`.

Here is the code:

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r"SimpleBoxTest.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

c=sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

#c = np.delete(c, (-1), axis=0) 

# c is a list, and not a numpy array, so use del instead of np.delete
# But why?
# del c[-1]

# Get one element before the last element in the list
c = c[-2] # Now c is a numpy.ndarray

extLeft = c[:, :, 0].min()
extRight = c[:, :, 0].max()
extTop = c[:, :, 1].min()
extBot = c[:, :, 1].max()

# Draw rectangle for testing
cv2.rectangle(image, (extLeft, extTop), (extRight, extBot), (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows();
```

---

### Update:

In case you want the second second extreme points among all contours you found, you may iterate the contours in `c`:

```
# Mark all contours with red:
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=5)

# Delete last element of the list
del c[-1]

# Initialize:
extLeft, extRight, extTop, extBot = 1e9, -1e9, 1e9, -1e9

# Iterate list and find the extreme points
for cc in c:
    extLeft = min(cc[:, :, 0].min(), extLeft)
    extRight = max(cc[:, :, 0].max(), extRight)
    extTop = min(cc[:, :, 1].min(), extTop)
    extBot = max(cc[:, :, 1].max(), extBot)

# Draw rectangle for testing
cv2.rectangle(image, (extLeft, extTop), (extRight, extBot), (0, 255, 0), thickness=5)
```

---

Solution without a using a for loop:

- You may use `np.vstack(c)` for concatenating the NumPy arrays in the list.
  Then find the extreme points in the concatenated array.

Code:

```
# Delete last element of the list.
del c[-1]

# Concatenate arrays along vertical axis.
c = np.vstack(c)

# Find extreme points:
extLeft = c[:, :, 0].min()
extRight = c[:, :, 0].max()
extTop = c[:, :, 1].min()
extBot = c[:, :, 1].max()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried the same code with other images, when there is a page full of text, getting the extreme points is the main aim. This code is won't help in that case .I will add a reference image to the same question. And Yeah! I understood down the line today it as list.

Comment: You can draw all contours: `cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=5)`. The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghrJL.png). The green box is around the second largest contour. What are the "second extreme points of the image"?

Comment: I updated my post. I hope that is what you have meant.

Comment: I love the way you had solved the issue in an optimized code.  I actually solved this issue later in the day in a very complex way. But this is the Best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The variable c is a list of array so add a for loop to iterate over it.
This solved the error:

```
for d in c:
    extLeft = tuple(d[d[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(d[d[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(d[d[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(d[d[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Comment: Yeah! it's a list but, when we do like the above code, we will not be able to find the extreme points, as it will be having extreme points of last list .